# Second signal not caught in my Solaris 11

Tags: c++, unix, signals, solaris

I have already registered the signal handler for SIGABRT. But only the first signal is caught. Second or subsequent signal goes for SIG_DFL and program terminates.

Below is the snippet from truss for the application process id

```
/1:     stat64("/zones/netiq/AM/log/nqmlog.lck", 0xFEFFE28C) = 0
/1:     stat64("/zones/netiq/AM/log/agent20160223061748.err", 0xFEFFE28C) = 0
/1:     stat64("/zones/netiq/AM/log/agent20160223052255.err", 0xFEFFE28C) = 0
/1:     stat64("/zones/netiq/AM/log/NqmAgt_4.log", 0xFEFFE28C) = 0
/1:     stat64("/zones/netiq/AM/log/NqmAgt_3.log", 0xFEFFE28C) = 0
/1:     stat64("/zones/netiq/AM/log/agent20160223052605.err", 0xFEFFE28C) = 0
/1:     stat64("/zones/netiq/AM/log/1.log", 0xFEFFE28C) = 0
/1:     stat64("/zones/netiq/AM/log/agent20160223061613.err", 0xFEFFE28C) = 0
/1:     stat64("/zones/netiq/AM/log/agent20160223052430.err", 0xFEFFE28C) = 0
/1:     stat64("/zones/netiq/AM/log/NqmAgt_1.log", 0xFEFFE28C) = 0
/1:     getdents64(5, 0xFC204000, 8192)                 = 0
/1:     close(5)                                        = 0
/1:     statvfs64("/zones/netiq/AM", 0xFEFFE224)        = 0
/7:     lwp_park(0xFBB82DB8, 0)                         Err#62 ETIME
/10:    lwp_park(0xFB885DB8, 0)                         Err#62 ETIME
/10:    time()                                          = 1456208362
/10:    time()                                          = 1456208362
/10:    time()                                          = 1456208362
/7:     time()                                          = 1456208362
/7:     time()                                          = 1456208362
/7:     time()                                          = 1456208362
/1:     write(3, " [ 2 0 1 6 - 0 2 - 2 3  ".., 125)     = 125
/1:     time()                                          = 1456208362
/1:     write(3, " [ 2 0 1 6 - 0 2 - 2 3  ".., 665)     = 665
/1:     time()                                          = 1456208362
/1:     time()                                          = 1456208362
/1:     time()                                          = 1456208362
/1:     time()                                          = 1456208362
/1:     time()                                          = 1456208362
/1:     time()                                          = 1456208362
/1:     write(3, " [ 2 0 1 6 - 0 2 - 2 3  ".., 114)     = 114
/1:     write(3, " [ 2 0 1 6 - 0 2 - 2 3  ".., 168)     = 168
/1:     write(3, " [ 2 0 1 6 - 0 2 - 2 3  ".., 146)     = 146
/1:     lstat64("/zones/netiq/AM/data/Config_1", 0xFEFFE1E0) = 0
/1:     rmdir("/zones/netiq/AM/data/Config_1")          Err#17 EEXIST
/1:     open("/zones/netiq/AM/data/Config_1", O_RDONLY|O_NDELAY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
/1:     fcntl(5, F_SETFD, 0x00000001)                   = 0
/1:     fstat64(5, 0xFEFFE1A0)                          = 0
/1:     pathconf("/zones/netiq/AM/data/Config_1", _PC_NAME_MAX) = 255
/1:     lwp_kill(1, SIGABRT)                            = 0
/1:         Received signal #6, SIGABRT [caught]
/1:           siginfo: SIGABRT pid=27656 uid=100 code=-1
/1:     lwp_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0x00029000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000) = 0xFFBFFEFF [0xFFFFFFFF]
/1:     chdir("/zones/netiq/AM/bin")                    = 0
/1:     setcontext(0xFEFFD8D0)
/1:     sigaction(SIGABRT, 0xFEFFE080, 0xFEFFE100)      = 0
/1:     lwp_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0x00029000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000) = 0xFFBFFEFF [0xFFFFFFFF]
/1:     lwp_kill(1, SIGABRT)                            = 0
/1:         Received signal #6, SIGABRT [default]
/1:           siginfo: SIGABRT pid=27656 uid=100 code=-1
```

Please let me know what should I do.

Code for signal handling

```
        static void
    SetSignals(void)
    {
    struct sigaction sa;
     sa.sa_handler = signalHandler;       /* Point to our signal handler func. */
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);            /* Clear mask */

   /* Block delivery of these signals during receipt of any one of them */
   sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGINT);
   sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGTERM);
   sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGSEGV);
   sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGBUS);
   sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGILL);
   sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGTRAP);
   sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGABRT);
   sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGFPE);
   sa.sa_flags = 0;                     /* No special flags */
   sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
   sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);
   sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
   sigaction(SIGBUS, &sa, NULL);
   sigaction(SIGILL, &sa, NULL);
   sigaction(SIGTRAP, &sa, NULL);
   sigaction(SIGABRT, &sa, NULL);
   sigaction(SIGFPE, &sa, NULL);

   /* Do nothing for SIGALRM. In release builds, it seems to kill us. */
   sa.sa_handler = doNothingHandler;
   sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask); /* Clear mask */

   sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

   sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
   sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
   sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask,SIGHUP);
   sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL);
    }
```

Signal Handler :

```
static void
signalHandler(int signum)
{
  char PathName[1024];
   UA_LOG_COMPONENT(MAIN, "main::signalHandler" );
   UA_LOG_BLOCK( DEBUG3 );


  if (g_Settings.m_strBinaryPath.length()) {
    strncpy(PathName, g_Settings.m_strBinaryPath, sizeof(PathName));
    PathName[sizeof(PathName) - 1] = 0;
  }
  else
    snprintf(PathName, sizeof(PathName), "%s/bin", g_Settings.m_strHomeDir.data());

  if (chdir(PathName) == -1)
    perror("UnixAgent: Could not change directory to UnixAgent home bin directory.");

   if (signum == SIGINT) {
       printf("UnixAgent: Got SIGINT\n");
       bRunning = false;
   }
   if (signum == SIGSEGV) {
       printf("UnixAgent: Got SIGSEGV\n");
       bSigINT = true;
       bRunning = false;
       ShmUpdateSegv(signum);
   }
   else if (signum == SIGTERM) {
       printf("UnixAgent: Got SIGTERM\n");
       bRunning = false;
   }
   else if (signum == SIGHUP) {
       printf("UnixAgent: Got SIGHUP\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not look like C++. C and C++ are different languages. Don't add the both tags for one language. Pick the one you use/compile as!

Comment: Try using `SA_SIGINFO` and `sa_sigaction` instead of `sa_handler`. BTW, why no `SA_RESTART`?

Comment: Post your signal handler code.

Comment: static void
signalHandler(int signum) {
   if (signum == SIGABRT) {
        printf("signalHandler\n");
   }
}

Comment: @Olaf : I checked with both g++ and gcc compiler. My sample application works as expected only. Both time registered signal handler is invoked. But in our application same kind of code is there which is not working

Comment: @Dummy00001 : Could you please let me know when we should use SA_RESTART ?

Comment: Even I tried to ignore the SIGABRT, But only the first time it ignores and the second time it goes to default handler.  I am able to see the mask changes for the second time. Wondering why ?

Comment: "It compiles" does not mean it works. And identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. To repeat: C and C++ are **different** languages! For C code use a C compiler. Also note that `gcc` is just a frontend driver which calls the actual compiler depending on the file extension.

Comment: @SrikanthGanesan *`static void signalHandler(int signum) { if (signum == SIGABRT) { printf("signalHandler\n"); } }`*  That doesn't match your truss output, where there's no output to `stdout` but there's a `chdir()` after `SIBABRT` gets caught.

Comment: Just now read https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals?page=show                                                                                       abort raises two consecutive signals registered signal handler is repositioned to default signal handler anyways. So there is no other to handle it or find why at least

Comment: @Olaf : We have used the C system call API's inside a C++ Application. Finally its C++ code/C++ Application

Comment: @SrikanthGanesan, `SA_RESTART` tries to restart interrupted syscalls. It lessens burden of handling the `EINTR` errors.

Comment: @SrikanthGanesan *abort raises two consecutive signals registered signal handler is repositioned to default signal handler anyways. So there is no other to handle it or find why at least*  What does the *Solaris* man page for `abort()` say?

Comment: @AndrewHenle : Thats what most of the forum or people say. But solaris man page says. Signal handler for abort doesn't return. Which means you can't return to the next line where the program was executing I hope. In the first time the we can use our signal handler to close the files...etc. In the second default handler it terminates the program anyhow

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Added signalHandler in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

If your Solaris uses the same `abort` as the one in Nevada (here's the [abort.c source](https://hg.openindiana.org/upstream/oracle/onnv-gate/file/b23a4dab3d50/usr/src/lib/libc/port/gen/abort.c)), it calls the user-installed handler for SIGABRT, if set, once, then goes into an infinite loop where it sets the handling for SIGABRT to SIG_DFL and then raises the signal.

If you want to do any cleanup, the single invocation of your handler is likely the only place to do it. Possibly you can do a `longjmp` out of it if you don't want the rest of `abort` to run.